# Your First ASP.NET 5 Web App Using Visual Studio (dnx ef database upgrade) not creating database/cmd error no sql connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

I am following the instructions from the link above. Everything works out till i get to dnx ef database update. At that point i get this error. [image]

When i debug this comes up. I am confused since i followed the instructions. 
[image]

Comment: `dnx ef database update` instead of `dnx ef database upgrade`?

Comment: my fault i am using update

Comment: as in the error message, I think you did not have the LocalDB installed

Comment: I have 2014 Developer. I am more SQL server but am starting to learn .net I have the AdventureWorks database but i am not sure what you mean by localdb?

Comment: can you post your connection string here? by saying `LocalDB`, I'm talking about this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/hh510202(v=sql.120).aspx). And I believe your connection string will looks have this line `Server=(LocalDb)\\ProjectsV13`.